# how to conver java class into visual class in eclipse?

Tags: java

i have swing code which is written in eclipse with out help of visual editor(not choose the class as visual class), now i need to modify that code using visual editor, how can i convert the a java class into visual class?

Answer (score 3):

Some Eclipse GUI builders (I think Jigloo, for example) do not store separate metadata and can therefore "reverse engineer" the class into the visual editor.

From the one time I tried it, however, I can tell you right now you should just invest the time in learning to use Swing by hand to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the class file and select **Open With** > **WindowBuilder Editor**. From now on eclipse will remember to edit the file using the WindowBuilder Editor.